# User Redirection accordingly an enum input. PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, enums

I'm trying to redirect the logged-in user to a different page according to the enum input was stored at db.

I was trying those lines, but it always redirects me at `pro.php`. How can I do this with the right way? What is the issue with the code?

Here is my table definition:

| # | Name | Type | Null | Default |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id | Primary int(11) | No | None | AUTO_INCREMENT |
| 2 | firstName | varchar(255) | Yes | NULL |  |
| 3 | lastName | varchar(255) | Yes | NULL |  |
| 4 | email | Index | varchar(255) | Yes | NULL |
| 5 | speciality | enum('pro', 'stu') | Yes | NULL |  |
| 6 | password | varchar(100) | Yes | NULL |  |
| 7 | lastLogin | timestamp | Yes | NULL |  |

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once("config.php");
include_once("session.php");

if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
  $errors = array();

  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "email is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) 
    {
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      $_SESSION["user_name"]=$firstName;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      $logintime = "UPDATE user SET lastLogin = now() where email = '$email'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $logintime);
      
      //Check speciality and redirect accordingly
      $speciality = $row['speciality'];
         if($speciality == "stu"){
        header("location:stu.php");
        }else{header("location:pro.php");}
    }else 
    {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        header("location:login.php");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I know the user is logged in because after the login, i'm going to db and see the lastLogin updated at the current user.

Comment: Also please explain what you've tried and where exactly you are getting stuck. "I want" isn't a question and doesn't explain a problem, and this site is not a free write-my-code service. See also the [tour] to familiarise yourself with how stackoverflow works. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, for future reference :-)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the update but... what debugging have you done? We can't see your table's _data_ yet, and we don't know what SQL query you ran or how you populated `$row`, so we don't know what `$row['speciality']` is going to contain. Can you show us those things? Have you tested that value in your code e.g. using `var_dump($row['speciality']);` or similar? Please provide a [mre] of the issue. Currently there isn't enough code or data in the question for us to fully understand the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you messed up the table formatting which I'd spend time on, when you didn't actually change the content of the table??!

Comment: Anyway, did you look through this code? It's quite clear that `$row` is never defined. There is no code which creates `$row` or gives it a value. Where exactly are you expecting that to come from? You should be getting a warning about an undefined variable when you try to use it. (If you aren't, then please switch on PHP error reporting).

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. `mysqli_real_escape_string` isn't 100% safe and can be bypassed in certain cases.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords using the obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm - that is another security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: Also, one more security problem in your code: you should always have `exit();` written directly after any `header("Location"...` command. `header` simply sets a header. It does not prevent the rest of the PHP script from executing. If someone is trying to view information they do not have permission for, then if you don't `exit` immediately after setting the redirect header, then PHP will still output the restricted data in the rest of the page, and it would be visible to the user in the browser's network tool if they choose to look, and/or visible to non-browser clients such as bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i change the speciality type enum to int(0 or 1) and some more things to the code and now is redirect me properly and almost everything working properly.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//also i hash the password with a better algorythm
$password = hash('sha256', $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
    $logintime = "UPDATE user SET lastLogin = now() where email = '$email'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $logintime);
    $_SESSION['speciality'] = $row['speciality'];
    if($_SESSION['speciality']==1) {header("Location: pro.php");}
    else{header("Location: stu.php");}
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Woops! Email or Password is Wrong.')</script>";
}
```

}